# Display daily event

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a table Events which has fields EventName and EventDateTime. I want to display daily time event on a listview or gridview or anything that looks like this:

DATE:                  TIME:

June 17, 2013       8:00-9:00 AM
                    1:00-4:00 PM

June 18, 2013       9:00-11:00 AM
                    3:00-6:00 PM

I have tried the SQL below. Im using ASP.net with c#. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT EventDateTime, EventName FROM Events GROUP BY EventDateTime, EventName
```

Comment: did u face any problem with above query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EventDateTime, EventName FROM Events GROUP BY CAST(EventDateTime AS DATE), EventName
```